# Bug? Answer count

Tags: support

The question ...in question:
[Is it legal in racket sports to pass the racket from one hand to the other?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/480/is-it-legal-in-racket-sports-to-pass-the-racket-from-one-hand-to-the-other)

As you can see on that page it only has 1 answer given. Yet when viewed in the question list here, it shows 2 answers given.
https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions

Anyone have any idea why that is? Maybe there's just something I don't understand about how the site works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To quote Grace Note:

> "Cache" and "Hover over it" are pretty much the answer to 90% of curious oddities or confusing UI on Stack Exchange.

In this case, it's caching. There was another answer, but it was deleted; you'll notice the same thing on [this question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/485/when-do-i-dispose-my-running-shoes) and a few others. The questions list should update to the correct value eventually.

Comment: ah, ok - I figured it might be something like that but didn't realize it gets cached for that long (hours, apparently?). Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @jamauss the more activity on the site, the lesser the cache length. In the case of early betas, it is easily low enough activity for a cache to last for a few hours.